# Probably simple regex search

Tags: .net, regex

What is the regex to find text#2? 
The pattern is that it's the first occurance of "z=" after c. The text I want is the rest of the line after z=. I'm using the regex in .Net

```
A
 x
 b
 x
 z=text#1
A
 x
 c
 x
 z=text#2
```

Comment: what should happen on A x c b z=text#2 ? or A x c A z=text#2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.*c.*z=([^\n]*).*
```

You'll need to turn on `.` matching newlines (`RegexOptions.SingleLine` below).

Here's some C# code generated by [My Regex Tester](http://www.myregextester.com/index.php):

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
namespace myapp
{
  class Class1
    {
      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          String sourcestring = "source string to match with pattern";
          Regex re = new Regex(@".*c.*z=([^\n]*).*",RegexOptions.Singleline);
          MatchCollection mc = re.Matches(sourcestring);
          int mIdx=0;
          foreach (Match m in mc)
           {
            for (int gIdx = 0; gIdx < m.Groups.Count; gIdx++)
              {
                Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames()[gIdx], m.Groups[gIdx].Value);
              }
            mIdx++;
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

To capture the *first* `z=whatever` after the `c`, you need to use a reluctant quantifier:

```
String source = @"A
 x
 b
 x
 z=text#1
A
 x
 c
 x
 z=text#2
A
 x
 d
 x
 z=text#3";

Match m = Regex.Match(source, @"c.*?z=([^\n]*)", RegexOptions.Singleline);
if (m.Success)
{
  Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[1].Value);
}
```

The regexes given in the other answers capture the *last* `z=whatever` after the `c`.  Since there's only the one `z=whatever` after the `c`, they get the expected result by accident.

Answer (score 1):

`c.+z=(.+)\n`

You'd have to set regex options so dot (.) matches everything